# Size values not unified into singular digits

Tags: c

I have a function that will take the size of an array, given a `MAXSIZE` defined value. It will eventually iterate over all values for `i` less than `size` however, when I map these values:

I get something like the following:

```
0 -> 0 0 0 0 0 171 140 14 240 171 140 14 1 0 0 0 ->> 255
1 -> 0 0 0 0 0 171 140 14 240 171 140 14 1 0 0 0 ->> 255
2 -> 0 0 0 0 0 171 140 14 240 171 140 14 1 0 0 0 ->> 255
3 -> 0 0 0 0 0 171 140 14 240 171 140 14 1 0 0 0 ->> 255
4 -> 0 0 0 0 0 171 140 14 240 171 140 14 1 0 0 0 ->> 255
5 -> 0 0 0 0 0 171 140 14 240 171 140 14 1 0 0 0 ->> 255
....
....
```

Why does `i/size` take the `MAXSIZE` value, and `size` produces many values?

I have found that, if I instead remodify the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < i/size; i++) //instead of

//for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

I instead get printed out the value `5`, where is this value coming from? This is coming from the division `255/51=5` but I cannot recognise where this is produced.

Code produced:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE 255
#define f sizeof(255)

int* MISE(int (*A)[MAXSIZE]){
    size_t size = sizeof(*A)/sizeof((*A)[MAXSIZE-1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < i/size; i++){
        printf("\n%i -> %vu ->> %i", i, size, i/size);
        (*A)[i] = i/size;
    }
    return (*A);
}

int main(void){
    int arr[MAXSIZE] = {(char*)(void*)(f+1)};
    int* result;
    result = MISE(&arr);
    printf("\n%i", *result);
    return *result;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the nonsensical casting, `f+1` is `sizeof(255)+1` = size of an `int` + 1, which apparently, on your platform, is `5` (`int` is apparently 4 bytes). I stared at this code for several minutes and have yet to grasp what on earth you're actually trying to do. `i < i/size` is nonsense; so long as `i` is >=0 and `size` is positive non-zero that expression will *never* be true. And in the context of its use, `sizeof(*A)/sizeof((*A)[MAXSIZE-1]);` is just an obfuscated way of writing `MAXSIZE`.

Comment: Is this some kind of intentionally obfuscated code?

Comment: @WhozCraig most helpful explanation! although, I am surprised `i < i/size` does not resolve to true, I can print it out as a `int` type, and it gives `255`. Not sure why though

Comment: Note that `%vu` is not a valid conversion specification.  You should print `size_t` values using `%zu`.  The double cast in the initialization of `A` in `main()` is weird.  I get compiler warnings and you should be getting them too.  Newlines should go at the end of format strings, not the beginning.  The test in `for(int i = 0; i < i/size; i++){` fails when `i` is `1`.

Comment: @ikegami I am only attempting to test what I have learnt so far, and see what I can or cannot do.

Comment: wherever you learned all this, never go there again. This is some weird code

Comment: You need to learn one thing: always read the warnings.

Comment: @pm100 Not sure I quite understand; I wanted to know why `i<size` is not initialised as a condition for the loop, but it's produced well inside the print function. I had remodified the code to do `(*A)[i] = *(A+i+i/size);
        printf("\n%i", (*A)[i]);` and find this decrements the memory address by 20, but does not return a value the pointer points to.

Comment: Re "*I am only attempting to test what I have learnt so far*", How about you tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it fail always Loop is never entered

Comment: @Emil11 To be clear `i < i/size` is false as in the first iteration with `i == 0`, `0 < 0/size` is false.  Instead code should use `for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){`.

Comment: @Emil11 With `i < size`, `i/size` is always 0, what did you expect code `(*A)[i] = i/size;` to do?

Answer (score 1):

> I instead get printed out the value 5, where is this value coming from?

From:

```
int arr[MAXSIZE] = {(char*)(void*)(f+1)};
...
printf("\n%i", *result);
```

`f+1` is like `sizeof(255)+1`

Hint: what is the size of `255`, an `int`?  It is not 255.  An `int`'s size is much smaller.

Note: Dodgy code is relying on `(void*)5` as being legitimate.